# Transit through through the Schengen area with an EEA Family Permit

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, chilean-citizens

I am a Chilean National and I have been granted EEA  Family Permit here in Chile, to join my husband in UK. I came from Oslo to Chile to issue my Family Permit. I would like to use my ticket return to Oslo and then travel from Oslo to UK. Can somebody  help  me, and tell me if I can go through Schengen area and use the return ticket to get to UK?

Comment: Yes.  That's fine.

Comment: @GayotFow EEA family permits are not necessarily "a settlement thing" -- they can also be used for short-term visits.

Comment: As a Chilean citizen, you don't need a visa short-term visits in the Schengen area. Why do you assume it should be a problem to transit in Oslo (with or without an EEA Family Permit)?

Answer (score 4):

Chile on the list of [Annex II countries](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2001R0539:20110111:EN:HTML) which means you can visit the Schengen zone countries for up to 90 days without applying for a visa. This also means that you can [freely transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) the Schengen area on any number of flights or connections.

You can show your EEA Family Permit at the border but it's not required that you do so.

Comment: Arguably the EEA family permit would enable her to use the EU/EEA/CH passports queue at Schengen borders, because she is traveling to join her husband and is therefore a "person enjoying freedom of movement under EU law."  The prospect of having to demonstrate that she is in fact joining her husband might be enough to keep this strategy from being worthwhile, but if there's a serious delay at the "all passports" desk then it might be worth trying.